# Alfresco - Replace /Sites by Company home?

Tags: rest, alfresco, multi-tenant

I'm using Alfresco 6 community edition in which I configured some sites, each site is associated with one tenant. (I saw last year alfresco multitenancy could be deprecated in community edition, so I chose to use sites).

But I heard it could be possible (and better) to use company home instead of sites to isolate my tenants.

I thought "Company Home" was the top level in the repository, how could I configured different company home in the same alfresco installation? I didn't found anything about this. Is it really possible? Did I miss something? Any info about this could help me.

To be complete, I connect my java application to alfresco using alfresco rest API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top folder in the Alfresco repository is called **Company Home**, although it will be referred to with the name **repository** in the Alfresco Share user interface. You can't have multiple companyHome in any alfresco installation.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-repository-concepts.html

**Features not supported in a multi-tenant environment**

There are some features and components that are not supported in a multi-tenant production environment. Not sure your feature occur under the below list.

Using multi-tenancy you can configure multiple, independent tenants on a single Alfresco Content Services instance. However, multi-tenancy is not supported in the following products and features:

```
Alfresco Desktop Sync
Alfresco Governance Services
Smart Folders
Content replication
Encrypted Content Store
Document Transformation Engine
EMC Centera Connector
Alfresco Mobile Applications (they use the default tenant and can't switch between tenants)
Alfresco Outlook Integration
Alfresco Media Management
Activiti Workflow Console
```

Arjun - Opentext

Comment: Thanks @Arjun. Multitenancy is still supported in Alfresco Community 6, but I read previously that it could be deprecated in community edition. Any info about this ?

Comment: Hey Philippe, Sorry for the confusion, yes for community edition there won't be any Multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Arjun's answer, you cannot have multiple roots/company home directories. You also cannot have multiple Sites folders. And, the Sites folder is flat, ie, all sites are immediate children of the Sites folder.

So, if you are trying to "roll your own" multi-tenancy, you will not be able to do so by segregating sites by parent folder per tenant.

Best to make them all private sites and just handle the segregation in your custom app.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, it’s what I do. Each tenant is associated with one site and one user. This user is used by my app to access alfresco. No access allowed outside my app.